# AWS4 s3 Put in Unity/C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

I would like to send an image to the AWS s3 bucket from my Unity project. to Connect to AWS there are several ways one of them is a direct request.
How do I use PUT request with the latest `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` supported singing?

Comment: This is not a good question. Even though you have also provided the answer, the question itself should be independently good. The question demonstrates no attempt to solve the issue, and honestly doesn't fully frame the problem.

Comment: let me rephrase it, honestly I was struggling to find it out, and just wanted to share the snippet.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class AWS3
{
    private const string awsBucketName = "YOUR BUCKET NAME";
    private const string awsAccessKey = "YOUR ACCESS KEY";
    private const string awsSecretKey = "YOUR SECRET KEY";
    private const string region = "eu-central-1";
    private const string serviceName = "s3";

    public static void UploadFileToAWS3(string FileName, string FilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            var endpointUri = $"https://{awsBucketName}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{FileName}";
            var requestUri = new Uri(endpointUri);

            string amzDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
            string dateStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

            // Step 1: Create Canonical Request
            var canonicalUri = $"/{FileName}";
            var canonicalQueryString = "";
            var canonicalHeaders = $"host:{requestUri.Host}\nx-amz-date:{amzDate}\n";
            var signedHeaders = "host;x-amz-date";
            var payloadHash = HashRequestBody(FilePath);
            var canonicalRequest = $"PUT\n{canonicalUri}\n{canonicalQueryString}\n{canonicalHeaders}\n{signedHeaders}\n{payloadHash}";

            // Step 2: Create String to Sign
            var credentialScope = $"{dateStamp}/{region}/{serviceName}/aws4_request";
            var stringToSign = $"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n{amzDate}\n{credentialScope}\n{SHA256Hash(canonicalRequest)}";

            // Step 3: Calculate the Signature
            var signingKey = GetSignatureKey(awsSecretKey, dateStamp, region, serviceName);
            var signature = Sign(stringToSign, signingKey);

            // Step 4: Add Authorization Header
            var authorizationHeader = $"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={awsAccessKey}/{credentialScope}, SignedHeaders={signedHeaders}, Signature={BitConverter.ToString(signature).Replace("-", "").ToLower()}";

            // Create and configure the request
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpointUri);
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.Headers.Add("x-amz-date", amzDate);
            // Adding x-amz-content-sha256 header
            request.Headers.Add("x-amz-content-sha256", payloadHash);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
            request.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";

            // Read the file content and write it to the request stream
            var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
            request.ContentLength = fileContent.Length;
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
            }

            // Send the request and get the response
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Response status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Web exception occurred: {ex.Message}");
            if (ex.Response != null)
            {
                using (var responseStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Response error: {responseText}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }


    private static byte[] GetSignatureKey(string key, string dateStamp, string regionName, string serviceName)
    {
        byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AWS4" + key), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dateStamp));
        byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(kDate, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(regionName));
        byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(kRegion, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serviceName));
        byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256(kService, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("aws4_request"));
        return kSigning;
    }

    private static byte[] HmacSHA256(byte[] key, byte[] data)
    {
        using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(key))
        {
            return hmacsha256.ComputeHash(data);
        }
    }

    private static string SHA256Hash(string value)
    {
        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashValue = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
            return BitConverter.ToString(hashValue).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }

    private static string HashRequestBody(string filePath)
    {
        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(stream);
            return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }

    private static byte[] Sign(string stringToSign, byte[] key)
    {
        return HmacSHA256(key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign));
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely wouldn't distribute this application to end users. It takes one bad actor to extract your secret key, and then you've got a huge Amazon bill after they upload a big file and make a billion copies of it. There's potentially worse things they could do, depending on the access the key gives them. You should have a separate API that generates signed URLs that doesn't place the key in the end user's possession.